# Browse lost heads with tig

Tags: git, tig

`tig` is a nice text-mode interface for Git, but it only shows the current branches.

How can I see lost heads and stashes in the tree view?

Answer (score 3):

For tree view it doesn't seem you can't. [Manual defines tree view as only working with current revision](http://jonas.nitro.dk/tig/manual.html#views).

You can switch tree view to refs or stash view though, from [tig manual](http://jonas.nitro.dk/tig/manual.html):

```
4.1. View Switching
Key     Action
[..]
r       Switch to refs view.
y       Switch to stash view.
```

AFAIK lost heads are only visible through reflog. As for viewing reflog,

> It is supported to some extend but probably not well documented. Try:
>
> git reflog --pretty=raw | tig --pretty=raw

([source](https://github.com/jonas/tig/issues/538))